# dynamoDB order results by column with and without a timestamp

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a dynamoDB table with items like:

```
{
  id: '123-abc-def',
  organisationId: '321-def-1ab',
  status: "Active",
  statusDateSortKey: "USED#"
},
{
  id: '123-abc-321',
  organisationId: '321-def-1ab',
  status: "Used",
  statusDateSortKey: "USED#1693321262"
}
```

I have a GSI on the table with `organisationId` as the partition Key and `statusDateSortKey` as the sort key.

I can run a query on the table to bring back items for an organisation sorted by `statusDateSortKey`, however, when sorting on ascending order, it'll bring back items with a `statusDateSortKey` missing a timestamp first, rather than items with a `statusDateSortKey` with the lowest value as the timestamp, followed by items missing the timestamp.

Removing `statusDateSortKey` from items where there is no timestamp allows me to sort correct in asc/desc order, but it won't bring back items without a `statusDateSortKey`.

Is there a way to be able to query in asc/desc order where `statusDateSortKey` contains a timestamp in asc/desc followed by items without, for example:

```
{
  id: '123-456-321',
  organisationId: '321-def-1ab',
  status: "Used",
  statusDateSortKey: "USED#1693180800"
},
{
  id: '123-abc-321',
  organisationId: '321-def-1ab',
  status: "Used",
  statusDateSortKey: "USED#1693321262"
},
{
  id: '123-abc-def',
  organisationId: '321-def-1ab',
  status: "Active",
  statusDateSortKey: "USED#"
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You're sorting [lexicographically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order), and that should be taken into consideration when designing the sort key.

Ideally you should not have a situation where some of the items have a date and others do not. I would just use timestamp as the sortkey, and omit the values and ultimately not project them if they dont have a date, but it depends on your specific use-case.

You just need to be aware you're sorting strings in lexicogrpahial order.